# number of non-congruent integer sided triangles with perimeter $n$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

For any natural number $n≥3$ let $f(n)$ denote the number of non-congruent integer sided triangles with perimeter n. which of the following is true?
$$A)f(1999)=f(1996)$$
$$B)f(2000)>f(1997)$$
$$C)f(2000)=f(1997)
$$
$$D)f(1999)<f(1996)$$
This is from ISI entrance mock test. I don't know how to start this one. Actually, I didn't understand the problem. Can someone please help me out with this and solve it or give me any related problems with solutions. That will help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Question rephrased: you have a triangle whose sides are all of integer length. Let's say that the side lengths to this triangle must add up to n. f(n) tells you how many different triangles there are that satisfy these conditions. Note: it doesn't make sense to have n =1,2. If you don't see why-- try drawing it.

Comment: Try to prove that $f(n+3) > f(n)$ starting from some $n$. It does solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Corrected answer:**

In a triangle, the greatest side must be less than the sum of the other two. If the perimeter $n$ and sides $a$, $b$, $c$ all have integer values, then you can calculate $f(n)$, the number of different triangles possible for any given perimeter $n$.

Supposing $a\ge b\ge c$, then$$\frac{n}{3}\le a <\frac{n}{2}$$As the comment of @paw88789 notes, for $n\ge11$ side $a$ of the triangle can have more than one value.

E.g. for $n=30$:$$\begin {array}{c|c}a & (b+c)\\\hline14 & (14+2), (13+3), (12+4), (11+5), (10+6), (9+7), (8+8)\\13 & (13+4), (12+5), (11+6), (10+7), (9+8)\\12 & (12+6), (11+7), (10+8), (9+9)\\11 & (11+8), (10+9)\\10 & (10+10)\end{array}$$Thus $f(n)=19$ when $n=30$.

$$\begin{array}{c|c}n & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15 & 16 & 17 & 18 & 19 & 20\\\hline f(n) & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 5 & 4 & 7 & 5 & 8 & 7 & 10 & 8
\end{array}$$$$\begin{array}{c|c}n & 21 &  22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 26 & 27 & 28 & 29 & 30 & 31 & 32 & 33 & 34 & 35 & 36\\\hline f(n) & 12 & 10 & 14 & 12 & 16 & 14 & 19 & 16 & 21 & 19 & 24 & 21 & 27 & 24 & 30 & 27\end{array}$$

But from the sample above, for $3\le n\le 36$, it can be seen that $f(n)$ varies somewhat irregularly with increasing $n$, obeying eight distinct laws rather than a single one, as follows:$$\begin {array}{c|c}n\pmod {12} & 48\cdot f(n)\\\hline1, 5 & n^2+6n-7\\2, 10 & n^2-4\\3 & n^2+6n+21\\4, 8 & n^2-16\\6 & n^2+12\\7, 11 & n^2+6n+5\\9 & n^2+6n+9\\0 & n^2\end{array}$$The four values of $n$ in the question posed, then, yield the following values for $f(n)$:$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}n & \pmod {12} & 48\cdot f(n) & f(n)\\\hline1996 & 4 & n^2-16 & 83,000\\1997 & 5 & n^2+6n-7 & 83,333\\1999 & 7 & n^2+6n+5 & 83,500\\2000 & 8 & n^2-16 & 83,333\end{array}$$Thus $C)$ is still the correct answer, but $f(n)$ is much greater than I first thought.

**Earlier mistaken answer:**

[In a triangle, the greatest side must be less than the sum of the other two. If the perimeter $n$ and sides $a$, $b$, $c$ all have integer values, then you can calculate $f(n)$, the number of different triangles possible for any given perimeter $n$.

Supposing $a\ge b\ge c$, and considering some smaller values of $n$:$$\begin {array}{c|ccc}n & a & (b+c)  & f(n)\\\hline10 & 4 & (4+2), (3+3) & 2\\11 & 5 & (5+1), (4+2), (3+3) & 3\\12 & 5 & (5+2), (4+3) & 2\\13 & 6 & (6+1), (5+2), (4+3) & 3\\14 &  6 & (6+2), (5+3), (4+4) & 3\\15 & 7 & (7+1), (6+2), (5+3), (4+4) & 4\\16 & 7 & (7+2), ( 6+3), 5+4) & 3\\17 & 8 & (8+1), (7+2), (6+3), (5+4) & 4\\18 & 8 & (8+2), (7+3), (6+4), (5+5) & 4\\19 & 9 & (9+1), (8+2), (7+3), (6+4), (5+5) & 5\\20 & 9 & (9+2), (8+3), (7+4), (6+5) & 4\\21 & 10 & (10+1), (9+2), (8+3), (7+4), (6+5) & 5\end{array}$$It is clear that $a=\frac{n}{2}-1$ for even $n$, and $a=\frac{n-1}{2}$ for odd $n$.

Moreover, as these few examples begin to illustrate, when $n$ is **even**$$f(n)=\frac{n-2}{4}$$for even $a$ and$$f(n)=\frac{n-4}{4}$$for odd $a$.

But when $n$ is **odd**$$f(n)=\frac{n-1}{4}$$for even $a$ and$$f(n)=\frac{n+1}{4}$$ for odd $a$.

And from these rules it follows that if$$n=1996, 1997, 1999, 2000$$then $$a=997, 998, 999, 999$$ and $$f(n)=498, 499, 500, 499$$respectively.

In the posed multiple-choice question, $A), B), D)$ are false and $C)$ is true.]

Comment: Aren't you  missing some triangles, such as $4,4,3$ (for $n=11$)?

Comment: Yes, I’ll try to correct this serious oversight in my approach.

Comment: @EdwardPorcella Thanks but it's a mere MCQ problem with just 4 minutes to work with this. So.....

Comment: To answer within four minutes I guess you’d have to know the rule that, for even $n$, $f(n)=\frac{n^2}{48}$, rounded to the nearest integer, and for odd $n$, $f(n)=\frac{(n+3)^2}{48}$, rounded also. This is simpler than my eight above expressions, (which I see also appear among the formulae for OEIS A005044).  What level of preparation does the ISI test presuppose, and what, if any, resources are available to the one taking the test?